# Job execution in Resque Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I have a basic question regarding job execution using Eesque.

I have a Rails application which submits jobs to Resque (backed with Redis).

Surprisingly I noted that while a job is getting executed if I kill Resque job still gets completed. New jobs of course can not be submitted since Resque is no longer running.

Hence my question is how come the job gets completed even if Resque was killed while it was executing ? Any thoughts ?

Comment: `kill -9` or `kill -TERM` (Ctrl+C) or anything else?

Comment: Actually my question is if Job is executing inside resque, should not killing resque, kill the job itself ?

Comment: killing resque wont kill the job which is being executed by a worker. ie job is not executing inside resque.. it executes as thread or we can assume as a process in the server